# How to use RestFB in Tomcat 7?

Tags: tomcat7, restfb

I am a newbie of JSP. May I ask how to install JAR file of [RestFB](http://restfb.com/) in Tomcat 7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the JAR in `TOMCAT_HOME\lib` folder, where `TOMCAT_HOME` is your root directory for Tomcat 7.

I would personally recommend that you put your JAR in your project's `WEB-INF\lib` folder, unless you have multiple applications that share restFB jar.

Comment: No problems, so did you do option 1) or 2)?

Comment: Option 2, as it won't affect other projects. Sadly, Tomcat does not have clear documentation (or I overlooked?)